# Slow wp-admin due to "SELECT DISTINCT post_mime_type FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'"

Tags: mysql, performance

The media library on a large site is slow in wp-admin. I did some research by looking into slow queries in the sql and found that this query is causing the slow response:

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_mime_type FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
```

It takes around 17 seconds and it's about 759000 rows of type 'attachment' in the db.

What would be the best way to optimize it or cache the distinct types? I don't want to change anything in core files.

Comment: You could try `ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD INDEX (post_mime_type);` and see if it helps...

Comment: I already did :D Now it takes "only" ~4 seconds. But right after I noticed another query counting each post takes around 9 seconds so I'm trying to remove it altogether.

Comment: So just to suggest something you're already doing again I suppose you're using the `query` filter to return literal sql statements if the problem statements match...